# Geometric explanations of approximations of $\pi$

Tags: geometry, soft-question, pi

Does any fast modern algorithm for approximating $\pi$ have a geometric interpretation as $\int \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common modern method for approximating $\pi$ are [Machin-like formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula). They work by writing $\pi$ as an integer combination of arctangents of small rational numbers, and then computing each arctangent by its power series.

The initial decomposition has a clear geometric flavor -- it amounts to finding a way to fill out a straight angle exactly by the corners of slim right triangles with integer ratios between the cathetes.

But there's nothing clearly geometric about the power series computation in the second phase.